# Javascript print array of numbers out in tabular format

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi I have an array of numbers and a K number which is the number of numbers on each line. I want to display numbers like this:

```
+---+---+
|123|  5|
+---+---+
|  6| 14|
+---+---+
```

so array = [123, 5, 6, 14] and K = 2, and there are pluses and minuses and pipes. The number of minuses is equal to number of digits in biggest number.

How can I write this in Javascript?
I have:

```
let res = ""
let max = Math.max(null, A)
let digits = max.toString().length;

function line(numPlus, numMinus) {
 let string  = "";
for (let i = 0; i  < numPlus; i++) {
  string += "+"
for(let j = 0; j < numMinus; j++) {
 string += "-"
}
string += "+"
}
}

line(K+1, digits);
```

Comment: Hi, perhaps loop over the array and print a top and bottom separator line for each iteration

Comment: Given your example I'm not sure the need for `K` - is it not possible to use the length of the array?

Answer (score 2):

```js
let array = [123, 5, 6, 14];
let k = 2;
let m = Math.max(...(array.map(e => e.toString().length)));
let t = new Array(k+1).fill("+").join("-".repeat(m));
let pa = array.map(e => e.toString().padStart(m, " "));
let str = "";
for (let i = 0; i < array.length/k; i++) {
  let s = pa.slice(k*i, k*i+k);
  while (s.length < k) s.push(" ".repeat(m));
  str += t + "\n|" + s.join("|") + "|\n";
}
console.log(str + t);
```

Comment: The only suggestion I might add is to calculate the max using `array.reduce((a, b) => a > b ? a : b, -Infinity).toString().length`. There might be speed improvements (although I'm not certain) to using this method over the combination of `.map` and `Math.max`

Comment: thanks! i edited my post so K= 2 and there are 4 elements in the array. how would you do that, if there are 2 rows?

Answer (score 1):

Something Like This Maybe

```js
let numbers = [100,25555,60,21,456,789,231,54,2,4,13,6,579,4562156, -5, 0.5, -1.5]
let maxLength = 0;

for(let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
    if(maxLength < numbers[i].toString().length){
        maxLength = numbers[i].toString().length
    }
}


function printDivider(cells){
    let row = '+';
    for(let i = 0; i < cells; i++){
        for(let j = 0; j < maxLength; j++){
            row+= '-'
        }
        row += '+';
    }
    console.log(row)
}



function printNumberRow(cells){
    let row = '|'
    for(let i = 0; i< cells; i++){
        if(numbers.length !== 0){
            let currentNumber = numbers.shift().toString();
            currentNumber = currentNumber.padStart(maxLength, ' ');
            row+=currentNumber;
        }
        else{
            row+= ''.padStart(maxLength, ' ');
        }
        row += '|';
    }
    console.log(row);
}

function printGraph(numbersPerRow){
    let maxRows = Math.round(numbers.length / numbersPerRow)
    if(numbers.length % numbersPerRow >= 1){
        maxRows++;
    }
    for(let i = 0; i < maxRows; i++){
        printDivider(numbersPerRow)
        printNumberRow(numbersPerRow)
        printDivider(numbersPerRow)
    }

}


printGraph(5)
```

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|    100|  25555|     60|     21|    456|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|    789|    231|     54|      2|      4|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|     13|      6|    579|4562156|     -5|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|    0.5|   -1.5|       |       |       |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Java solution. I am just formatting [@user17315860](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17315860/user17315860) answer.
His answer is correct but not at all ridable.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Solution {
    static void solution(int[] A, int K) {
        int maxLength = 0;

        ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int x : A) {
            arr.add(x);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            if (maxLength < Integer.toString(A[i]).length()) {
                maxLength = Integer.toString(A[i]).length();
            }
        }
        int completeRow = A.length / K;
        int iRow = A.length % K;
        if (completeRow > 0) {
            printDivider(K, maxLength, arr);
        } else {
            printDivider(iRow, maxLength, arr);
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < completeRow; i++) {
            printNumberRow(K, maxLength, arr);
            System.out.println();
            printDivider(K, maxLength, arr);
            System.out.println();
        }
        if (iRow > 0) {
            printNumberRow(iRow, maxLength, arr);
            System.out.println();
            printDivider(iRow, maxLength, arr);
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

    static void printDivider(int cells, int maxLength, ArrayList<Integer> A) {
        String row = "+";
        for (int i = 0; i < cells; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < maxLength; j++) {
                row += "-";
            }
            row += "+";
        }
        System.out.print(row);
    }

    static public void printNumberRow(int cells, int maxLength, ArrayList<Integer> A) {
        String row = "|";
        for (int i = 0; i < cells; i++) {
            if (A.size() != 0) {
                int num = A.get(0);
                A.remove(0);
                // String currentNumber = Integer.toString(num);
                String aa = "";
                int intlength = Integer.toString(num).length();
                for (int j = 0; j < maxLength - intlength; j++) {
                    aa = aa + " ";
                }
                aa = aa + Integer.toString(num);
                row += aa;
            }
            // else{
            // row+= ''.padStart(maxLength, ' ');
            // }
            row += '|';
        }
        System.out.print(row);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] A = new int[] { 4, 35, 80, 123, 12345, 44, 8, 5, 24, 3,22,35 };
        solution(A, 4);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//A simple and effective solution for exact result
import java.util.*;

class Solution {
public void solution(int[] A, int K) {

```
int maxLength = 0;

ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
for(int x :A){
    arr.add(x);
}
for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
    if(maxLength < Integer.toString(A[i]).length()){
        maxLength = Integer.toString(A[i]).length();
    }
}
    int completeRow = A.length / K;
    int iRow = A.length % K;
    if(completeRow>0){
        printDivider(K, maxLength,arr);
    }
    else{
        printDivider(iRow,maxLength,arr);
    }
    System.out.println();
    for(int i=0;i<completeRow;i++){
        printNumberRow(K, maxLength,arr);
        System.out.println();
        printDivider(K, maxLength,arr);
        System.out.println();
    }
    if(iRow > 0){
        printNumberRow(iRow, maxLength,arr);
        System.out.println();
        printDivider(iRow, maxLength,arr);
        System.out.println();
    }

}

void printDivider(int cells, int maxLength ,ArrayList<Integer> A){
String row = "+";
for(int i = 0; i < cells; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < maxLength; j++){
        row+="-";
    }
    row += "+";
}
System.out.print(row);
```

}

public void printNumberRow(int cells,int maxLength, ArrayList A){
String row = "|";

```
for(int i = 0; i< cells; i++){
    if(A.size() != 0){
        int num=A.get(0);
        A.remove(0);
        // String currentNumber = Integer.toString(num);
        String aa = "" ; 
        int intlength = Integer.toString(num).length() ; 
        for(int j = 0  ; j < maxLength-intlength ; j++ ) {
            aa = aa+" " ;
        }
        aa =aa +  Integer.toString(num) ;
        row+=aa;
    }
    // else{
    //     row+= ''.padStart(maxLength, ' ');
    // }
    row += '|';
}
System.out.print(row);
```

}

}